# delayed hardware register writing on linux kernel driver

Tags: linux, kernel, delay

I am writing kernel driver and it needs two group hardware register setting. that is, second hardware setting need to wait for specific time(m sec) after first hardware register setting.
I want to get the method with small variation.
1. mdelay
2. tasklet
3. schedule_timeout using sleep mode.
4. timer interrupt
5. work queue

I wonder which method support accurate delay without system impact.
mdelay -> it is poor method due to poor system performance.
timer interrupt: I wonder if it is good method to set h/w register in the handler
tasklet: it looks good. but wonder if it has same question like timer interrupt.
work queue: it has big variation.

Comment: Since, you know exactly how much time to wait, there's no reason to consider anything other then mdelay(). I think hardware registration will be done once and it's not repetitive, so I think it's best for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks does 6ms delay  make any performance issue? How about Schedule_timeout method for it?

Comment: If I'm not wrong mdelay() uses schedule_timeout() implicitly. They both put the running context into sleep.